# firebase setup on android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, build.gradle

I can't setup the updated version of firebase on android studio.
I've created json file of the project on the site firebase and copied it into the project and after coping lines in gradle:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  // ...
}
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
}
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I get the following error:

`failed to resolve: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try updating Google Play Services in the SDK.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem. If you are using Android studio, you should then update `google repository` in SDK Manager.

[image]

Following is my **build.grade(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my **build.grade(project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Volley, okhttp, **and** apache http? Why?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry you just took what you need. i told that was my build.gradle. anyway i did edit and removed them

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is working based on Google Play Services. So please make sure you have the following sdk tools and they are updated to sync against the library versions of firebase that you are using.

[SDK Tools installed for this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcy2e.png)

Project level **build.gradle** file

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Module Level **build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devdeeds.firebaseauth"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```