# Gradle not compiling for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging

I noticed that Firebase APIs have upgraded from v 9.0.0 to v 9.0.1 and so decided to change that.

However it is not getting noticed.

Here is the Error in Gradle Logcat

```
   Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1
   Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1
```

And here are my Gradle Files

## Build.Gradle-> App

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lifeline.applicationgreat"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

## Build.Gradle-> Project

```
     // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
} 
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

Can Anyone tell whats the Error or if I am Missing anything.
Also Is there any requirement of Firebase-core for Cloud Messaging?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue with "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.1", what I did was install from de SDK Manager Google Repository Extra.

Answer (score 9):

You have to update/install     Google Repository, revision 27

Check this answer: [firebase setup on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499006/firebase-setup-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to go to the Android SDK manager and check for updates - you should see an update to the Google Play services SDK which will resolve these dependencies.

Comment: I just tried that, still it is not working. Initially an error came regarding a problem with Daemon, but after recompiling it 3 times the same error is coming again

Answer (score 0):

For mac os users, a part from updating your SDK, if you have installed the ADK with and without brew, be sure to check that the path for your ADK in Android studio is the correct one. My problem was that android studio reverted to the old path on its own.