# Google Play services out of date. Requires 9877000 but found 9875480 with google firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

Here is my gradle.app 
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.joshpc.bluetoothattendee"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I try to run my android emulator it is giving me this read out:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9875480
```

I have tried reverting firebase and google play services to 9.6.0 which does not work as firebase requires 9.8.0

I have updated my API 25 android system images in the stand alone SDK manager.

My google play repository is up to date.

if I change my gradle to call for play services 9.8.7 it gives me the error:

[image]

So i'm not quite sure how to go about fixing this issue or updating the play services when the SDK says its up to date and I can't revert the version required. 
note that the "install repository and sync" isnt clickable/doesnt link to anything. I checked the repository version and its up to date

Comment: see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499006/firebase-setup-on-android/37499376#37499376)

Comment: I am currently trying API 24. will see if it works

Comment: it appears the error you fixed is different to the one I am receiving. It resolves firebase and creates the link just fine, but the error is in regards to google play services.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play services out of date. Requires 9877000 but found 9875470](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567672/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-9877000-but-found-9875470)

Comment: Don't repost, please. Comments don't bump. Edits to the question do

Comment: thank you. did not know! apologies

Answer (score 0):

The emulator image for API level 25 (7.1.1) did not get updated with the latest Play services along with the other API levels.  For now, if you want to use client library version 9.8.0, you should test against level 21-24, as the update was made available for them on November 11.