# Google Play services out of date. Requires 9877000 but found 9875470

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, google-play-services

Here is my gradle.app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.joshpc.bluetoothattendee"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I try to run my android emulator it is giving me this read out:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9875480
```

I have tried reverting firebase and google play services to 9.6.0 which does not work as firebase requires 9.8.0

I have updated my API 25 android system images in the stand alone SDK manager.

My google play repository is up to date.

if I change my gradle to call for play services 9.8.7 it gives me the error:

[image]

And if i downgrade GPS to 9.6.0, I get this:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

So i'm not quite sure how to go about fixing this issue or updating the play services when the SDK says its up to date and I can't revert the version required. 
note that the "install repository and sync" isnt clickable/doesnt link to anything. I checked the repository version and its up to date

I checked the version in my emulator and it is running 9.8.75

Comment: `compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` Should not be there

Comment: removed it. still throwing `Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9877000 but found 9875470`

Comment: `'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'` is the old Firebase. Where did you see to add that?

Comment: honestly, youtube. updated it to `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'` and still throws error

Comment: Well, firstly, [9.8.0 is the latest](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), so I do not know why you tried `9.8.7`

Comment: that came from trying suggestions on stack overflow posts

Comment: This post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249454/how-to-update-google-play-services-to-9-8-7

Comment: indeed. which is where i tried 9.6 as well

Comment: Well, as that post said, a physical device should work, but the Google APIs system image was not released (at the time)

Comment: alright I just tested it on my phone (API 23) and it is still giving me `Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.`

Comment: The emulator for API level 25 did not get updated. See also information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562307/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-9877000-but-found-9875480-with-google

Comment: @DougStevenson you linked to post by same OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run on the emulator you have configured with a system image that contains version 9875480 of the Google APIs, your only option is to downgrade the versions of Google Play Service and Firebase APIs:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
    //compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    //compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Although you say you did this and still get the same warning, I question that.  I am able to build with these dependencies and run on an emulator with version 9875480 of the Google APIs.

If you want to build with version 9.8.0, I think you need to run on a real device.  I don't think any emulator images have been released that support 9.8.0, at least not for API 25.

Comment: this does *not* give me the google play services error, but instead it gives me `Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.`

Comment: That warning can be ignored. It's harmless.

Comment: so what this means my code is not working due to another reason?

Comment: Although I don't know what in your code is not working, I'm almost certain that warning is not the problem.  I've been seeing it for months and am able to authorize users, read/write data, and perform many other Firebase actions.

Comment: alright i will look into this issue more. Thank you for the info!

Comment: ah yes. the login code is indeed executing and that error is useless info. Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

just change this line :`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'`
to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.0'
```

and every thing should work well

and for the firebase try this :
    `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'`

Comment: Why are you recommending downgrading?